# AppLovin Bidding Network very low eCPM with AppLovin Mediation

Tags: admob, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

I'm using AppLovin Mediation and when I look at my performances by networks I can see the eCPM for "AppLovin Bidding" is at least 5 times smaller than other networks. Unfortunately, most of my requests are pointing to that "AppLovin Bidding". I wondering if there is a way to prioritize other networks or if there are settings to boost eCPM for that specific network.

Otherwise, do you think implementing a Bid Floor CPM could improve that eCPM? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, you will not always get high eCPM, so this is act like a backfill.

to make it more clear; when you are getting 0.01 eCPM for Applovin, in that moment you are getting less than 0.01 from other networks.